# MongoDB - Compond Geo Polygon Indexing

Tags: mongodb

I have several geo queries which look similar to the below example.  They are not only a point in Poly query but have other aspects to it.

Query:

```
{
"point": {
    "$within": {
        "$polygon": [
            [
                41.878335,
                -87.627319999999997
            ],
            [
                41.877602000000003,
                -87.627319999999997
            ],
            [
                41.879672999999997,
                -87.627031000000002
            ],
            [
                41.878723999999998,
                -87.627204000000006
            ],
            [
                41.878507999999997,
                -87.627262000000002
            ],
            [
                41.878335,
                -87.627262000000002
            ]
        ]
    }
},
"MYLISTING": {
    "$in": [
        "All"
    ]
},
"SUPPORT": {
    "$in": [
        "Y"
    ]
},
"TYPE": {
    "$in": [
        "Food"
    ]
}
}
```

To help make these quicker I added each of the other items to an index making it:

```
{   "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "point" : "2d",
        "MYLISTING" : 1,
        "SUPPORT" : 1,
        "TYPE" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "mydb.collection",
    "name" : "point_2d_MYLISTING_1_SUPPORT_1_TYPE_1"
}
```

However when doing an explain on this, it never seems to be using this index, it's simply using the other index I have which is only the point:2d index initially created.

is there some mis-understandign I'm having here?

Comment: Try running explain with an argument of "true". This will generate stats for all query plans and not just the optimal one. It may provide more information on why your query is using the index it is.

Comment: you cannot have more than one '2d' index on a collection (you have two, simple '2d' and one with additional fields).  This is mentioned in the docs page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one geo index - now you have two, where one of the parts is part of your compound index. The limitation is mentioned in the documentation: http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Geospatial%20Indexing.html#GeospatialIndexing-CreatingtheIndex

The solution would be to simply drop the index that you have on just the spatial field:

```
db.yourCollection.dropIndex( { point: '2d' };
```

When you then run your query, with explain(), you see which index is now used again - and in this case, that should be the compound index. Also make sure, that the geo spatial field is the first part of your compound index as described here: http://api.mongodb.org/wiki/current/Geospatial%20Indexing.html#GeospatialIndexing-CompoundIndexes